# Approximate Plane Equation Calculator

Tags: data-visualization, math

I need a visual geometry tool.

I want to drag&drop and rotate the default z=0 plane and when I'm doing this, I need the approximate equation of the modified plane.

For instance, if I move the plane higher, it becomes z = 1, z = 1.54, z = 2 etc.

When I rotate it, it may become 2x + 4y + z - 3 = 0 or so.

Is there any tool for this?